# How to fixed trait method collision and rename method in php

Tags: php, traits

How to rename a method that conflict in PHP trait, rename and define `insteadof` in a single line.

```
trait Hello
{
    public function say()
    {
        return 'Hello';
    }
}

trait World
{
    public function say()
    {
        return 'World!';
    }
}
```

This one works perfectly

```
class HelloWorld
{
    use Hello, World {
        Hello::say insteadof World;
        Hello::say as sayHello;

        World::say insteadof Hello;
        World::say as sayWorld;
    }
}

$obj=new HelloWorld();
echo $obj->sayHello(). ' '.$obj->sayWorld(); //Hello World
```

How to write in a single line instead of and rename look like this

```
//not working
class HelloWorld
{
    use Hello, World {
        Hello::say insteadof World as sayHello;
        World::say insteadof Hello as sayWorld;
    }
}

$obj=new HelloWorld();
echo $obj->sayHello(). ' '.$obj->sayWorld(); //nothing
```

Comment: Is there any problem with the 2 line version?

Comment: @NigelRen no, just want to have any simple way ?

Comment: @Al-Amin `World::say insteadof Hello;` is not needed.

Comment: @vivek_23 need one either `Hello::say insteadof World;` or   `World::say insteadof Hello;`